# You do not have the proper encryption level to access this session

Tags: windows-server-2003, rdp

I'm getting this error when I try to log into our Windows Server 2003 SP1 32-bit server via RDP console.

> you do not have the proper encryption
>   level to access this session

Any ideas why this is coming up?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this? http://www.eggheadcafe.com/forumarchives/windowsservernetworking/Jul2005/post23152125.asp

Or, from **http://www.lshtm.ac.uk/its/remote/faq.htm**:
**Q.** I get an error message “You do not have the proper encryption level to access this Session”
**A.** Your connection settings do not have encryption on login enabled. Replace your desktop icon with a new copy (right-click and save it to your desktop). If you have set up your connection manually, ensure the encryption level is set to "128-bit Login Only"

Answer (score 0):

Ensure that your encryption is set to 128bit. If you set it to 128-bit login only will give the same error